# UFW and Elementary OS 5 - Juno

Tags: release-juno, networking, system

I have a new, fresh installation of Elementary OS 5 - Juno on a Razer Blade Stealth (2018).  All of the updates have been applied (as of 02/02/19).  I want to enable the firewall through System Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall.  I unlock the settings to allow changes to the system.  After the firewall (ufw) is enabled, I get the following prompt about every seven minutes:

Authentication is required to run the Firewall Configuration.

Entering the password gives you about seven additional minutes before having to re-authenticate the firewall.  Then it becomes a constant rinse and repeat series of events...

```
$ journalctl --follow
Feb 02 00:20:23 (hostname) io.elementary.p[1710]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Feb 02 00:20:23 (hostname) gala.desktop[1676]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2002d31 (Authentica)

Feb 02 00:27:07 (hostname) io.elementary.p[1710]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Feb 02 00:27:07 (hostname) gala.desktop[1676]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2003980 (Authentica)

Feb 02 00:33:29 (hostname) io.elementary.p[1710]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Feb 02 00:33:29 (hostname) gala.desktop[1676]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x200474a (Authentica)

$ ps -eaf | grep (processID)
(userID)   1710  1381  0 00:00 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/policykit-1-pantheon/io.elementary.pantheon-agent-polkit
(userID)   1676  1381  4 00:00 ?        00:01:39 gala
```

Reboot

```
$ journalctl --follow
Feb 02 01:16:16 (hostname) io.elementary.p[1633]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Feb 02 01:16:16 (hostname) gala.desktop[1592]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2001cd5 (Authentica)

Feb 02 01:22:29 (hostname) io.elementary.p[1633]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Feb 02 01:22:29 (hostname) gala.desktop[1592]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2003813 (Authentica)

$ ps -eaf | grep (processID)
(userID)   1633  1315  0 01:05 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/policykit-1-pantheon/io.elementary.pantheon-agent-polkit
(userID)   1592  1315  6 01:05 ?        00:00:48 gala
```

As you can see from my log snippets, the error continues after a reboot.

Any suggestions, comments or assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am seeing the exact same behaviour with the exact same error message. It started the instant I enabled firewall. I'm running Hera with all updates. Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have worked it out.

Elementary OS supplies its own GUI to manage ufw. The GUI has to be unlocked before it can be used.

Am I correct in thinking that the GUI relocks itself after a timeout period, and then demands re-authentication?